# Windows 11 can't install because of my processor and I want to keep it that way

Tags: windows-11

I don't want Windows 11 and I want to stick with Windows 10 for the time being. Is there the possibility that Microsoft is going change it's mind and decided my processor (i7-7700) is good enough in the future and force the upgrade on me?

I have old software my elderly father depends on and since it appears Windows 10 will be supported till 2025 I don't feel like risking it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there the possibility that Microsoft is going change it's mind and decided my processor (i7-7700) is good enough in the future and force the upgrade on me?

There is **no chance** this will happen. If Microsoft had any plans for Windows 11 to support 7th Generation Intel Core processors, they would have already made that announcement before October 5th, 2021.

> I have old software my elderly father depends on and since it appears Windows 10 will be supported till 2025 I don't feel like risking it.

The only way an incompatible device can be upgraded to Windows 11 is to set `AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU` to `1` before manually performing the upgrade with the `Windows 11 Installation Assistant` or the `Windows 11 Media Creation Tool`.  Incompatible devices will not be offered the upgrade through Windows Update.

If you are still afraid, despite a less than 0% chance of this happening, you can set the following registry keys to prevent any future upgrade.

- `TargetReleaseVersion` to `1` - 32-bit DWORD
- `TargetReleaseVersionInfo` to `21H1` - String Value

Both of these keys should exist within `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate`, and if the keys do not exist, you should create them.

You will want to change the value of `TargetReleaseVersionInfo` to `21H2` once that version is released for Windows 10.  **As a reminder, Windows 10 21H2 is the last version of Windows 10.**

Of course, since the device in question is not compatible unless you go to the extra step of manually installing Windows 11 yourself, it will never be upgraded to Windows 11 automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has not publicly decided on older processors and if they change their mind, the upgrade will not be unannounced or automatic.

So there is nothing to be done at this point since your machine will not upgrade because of processor generation.

For the next few months (the next year) keep watch and see if Microsoft changes their position. Likely not, but keep watch.

Maybe gradually update software in any event for that time when you wish to upgrade or buy a new computer.

I have just received a new Desktop computer (existing one has no TPM chip or header) and even it is not upgrading automatically.