# Installing windows 11 on unsupported computer

Tags: windows, cpu, tpm

I want to install windows 11 but my pc is unsupported, here are my specs

```
Device name iMac
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6400T CPU @ 2.20GHz   2.21 GHz
Installed RAM   7.89 GB
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
```

on PC health check it shows
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoPP6.png)
Although, my pc is unsupported but i want to download windows 11
i checked youtube and found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovgWN6YD2ws&lc=Ugy_vvaK007PG2wp7UB4AaABAg.9TnwhLX-w6f9Tql33l8GRL). `Installing windows 11 using ISO file on an unsupported PC`. In the video they have shown that download windows 11 iso file from microsoft's website (which i have already installed). next they tell to edit the the registry editor at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\MoSetup` but in my pc. there is no folder called `MoSetup` at this path. [here is a look of my registry editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPCiZ.png). It would be great if someone could help.
Thanks

Comment: Why exchange a fully-working OS for a crippled one? You will not get updates, some Win11 features will not work, etc. The differences between Windows 10 and 11 are really minimal and do not warranty this effort. And in addition this is an iMac.

Comment: If you read (listen) to the instructions again they suggest you have to create the key if it does not exist.  It should be as simple as setting [AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU](https://superuser.com/questions/1682450/windows-11-cant-install-because-of-my-processor-and-i-want-to-keep-it-that-way/1682456#1682456) to 1. Full written instructions are [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e).  There are also third-party scripts that will do this for you.

Comment: Stay with Windows 10 until the computer wears out and replace with a Windows 11 computer

Answer (score 0):

Works without secure boot, tpm and unsupported cpu.

What you need

- bootable windows 10 usb
- windows 11 iso

Mount the windows 11 iso. Navigate to the /sources and copy the install.esd

Connect (if not already) the bootable usb, and navigate to its /sources

If it has [install.wim] delete it. If it has [install.esd] delete/replace with the copied one from the iso.

Once completed, reboot to usb, and install.
*it will say windows 10 installation, but it’s actually windows 11*