# Your device is not eligible to join the windows insider program on windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-insider

I was a Dev-Channel Insider when there was no Windows11.
Once upgrading from win10 to win11 became available for Dev-Channel insiders, I did so.

Now that I'm using Windows11, I want to become Dev-Channel insider again. But windows11 does not let me to join the program.

This is the screenshot of the error:
[image]

Does anyone know some hacks or tricks in order to ditch this error and join the insider program?

I'm using Windows 11 Enterprise, build 22000.348 version 21H2

Thank You.

Comment: https://insider.windows.com/en-us/getting-started   ..... You can also register for the Windows Insider Program for Business with your work account.

Comment: Windows 11 Insider Preview builds have the same system requirements that Windows 11 has, if you are getting this message, it means your not running a supported processor. The proper solution is to upgrade your processor to that one that is supported by Windows 11.

Comment: Is your Windows 11 Enterprise version working properly (question to OP)?

Comment: You can also enable [AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU](https://superuser.com/questions/1682450/windows-11-cant-install-because-of-my-processor-and-i-want-to-keep-it-that-way/1682456#1682456).  You might have to download the appropriate Developer channel Windows Insider Preview ISO to install the update since you are runing on unsupported hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound I know that my laptop is not supported, I am looking for some tricks in order to ditch it.

Comment: @John yes it is working properly.

Comment: Since you know the laptop is not supported and it's telling you that it is not supported, is the solution not obvious ?  The requirements would be hardware ones.  Have you tried pressing on <kbd>Learn More</kbd> ?  It may give you more information.  You are asking us to guess why its not suitable!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know some hacks or tricks to ditch this error and join the insider program?

Since you are already running Windows 11 on unsupported hardware, the simplest solution is to set [`AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e) to `1` and then download the current Developer channel ISO [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso) and perform the upgrade[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1682450/windows-11-cant-install-because-of-my-processor-and-i-want-to-keep-it-that-way/1682456#1682456)

The only other alternative is to upgrade your hardware to a supported processor.

I verified that I could download an Enterprise ISO from the website I linked, an alternative to the one I provided is [uupdump.net](https://uupdump.net/fetchupd.php?arch=amd64&ring=wif&build=latest), but that requires running a script.

> Can I update my windows which is Enterprise, with that ISO which does not contain the Enterprise edition? –

No