# How to Update Windows 11 to latest as 5 months ago I downloaded its Dev version on my Windows 10Pro

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-preview

How to Update Windows 11 to latest, as 5 months ago I downloaded its Dev version on my Windows 10 Pro Licensed Laptop.

Here is the Version Name from About Windows Information:
i.imgur.com/Mj6UACR.png

How can I now update manually from Windows ISO files, where will I get those files?
As from the Windows Insider channel or Dev channel I haven't yet received any update so far, maybe it is due to my Device Does not support Windows 11.

I have Dell Latitude E7470 (16GB RAM, 500GB SSD) mase in March 2017.

Here is the PC Health Check Result:
i.imgur.com/hBL6wjd.png

Comment: You question links do not work. Try pasting the images into your question. That is needed to know if your computer supports Windows 11.

Comment: Is your PC compatible with Windows 11? If not the only way is to use a clean install using the appropriate registry key to bypass the required restrictions. There are half a dozen questions like this but [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1693112/your-device-is-not-eligible-to-join-the-windows-insider-program-on-windows-11/1693116#1693116) appears to be the best duplicate. I strongly suggest going to the 21H2 Windows 11 build and immediately STOP receiving Insider Preview builds.